# Is there a way to create a .Net Core class library that reference ASP.NEt core without beeing a netcoreapp

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

We are making a app template that make use of a shared API library with API controllers. (Avaiable from Nuget)

Since API controllers take use of Microsoft.AspNetCore we are forced to make the library target netcoreapp30.

That again forces us to create startup.cs and program.cs in that library to make it compile.

Is there a way to make a class library refernce needed aspnetcore stuff without beeing required to create the startup.cs and program.cs? (compiler complains about missing start point without them)

Startup.cs and program.cs we have in the app using the nuget.

Our project file for the library

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>`. Without it the compiler makes assumptions about what you want (library for netstandard, app for netcore).

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert  It was the perfect solution :-)